# Why can't all diagonalizable matrices be decomposed into $Q\Lambda Q^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition

I am a beginner Linear Algebra student and I have the following question:

If a matrix is diagonalizable matrix can be decomposed into $A = S\Lambda S^{-1}$, where $S$ is a matrix of $A$'s eigenvectors, can I simply orthogonalize via Gram-Schmidt and then normalize those vectors to change $S$ into $Q$, and then use $A = Q\Lambda Q^T$?

Comment: No you cannot do that.

Comment: You could also try, say eith a 2 by 2 matrix, and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Because if $A$ can be diagonalized with an orthogonal matrix, eigenvectors relative to different eigenvalues are *orthogonal*. This may not happen for a diagonalizable matrix.

Indeed, suppose $Av=\lambda v$ and $Aw=\mu w$, with $\lambda\ne\mu$. Then
$$
\lambda\langle v,w\rangle=
\langle \lambda v,w\rangle=
\langle Av,w\rangle=
\langle Q\Lambda Q^Tv,w\rangle=
\langle v,Q\Lambda^TQ^Tw\rangle=
\langle v,Aw\rangle=
\mu\langle v,w\rangle
$$
and so $(\lambda-\mu)\langle v,w\rangle=0$, hence $\langle v,w\rangle=0$ (since $\Lambda$ is diagonal, $\Lambda=\Lambda^T$).

If you apply Gram-Schmidt to the columns of $S$ there's no reason for the matrix $Q$ you get to have eigenvectors of $A$ as columns.

By the way, this shows that if a real matrix $A$ is diagonalizable with an orthogonal matrix, then it is *symmetric*.